# What is the coefficient of $q^n$ in the Lambert Series Expansion $a^2(q).a(q^5)$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

What is the coefficient of $q^n$ in the Lambert Series Expansion $a^2(q).a(q^5)$. Here $a(q)$ is **Borwein Theta Function**.

I am using **Ramanujan's Theta Functions** Book by **Shaun Cooper** as a reference material and I am suppose to find the coefficient of $q^n$ in the lambert series for $a^2(q).a(q^5)$. But, I have no idea how to proceed. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Kindly provide me some hints or some resources that I can avail where I can find more about this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure where the [Lambert series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_series) comes in since $\,a^2(q).a(q^5) = 1 + 12q + 36q^2 + 12q^3 + 84q^4 + 78q^5 + \cdots \,$ but Lambert series have a coefficient $0$ of $\,q^0.$

Comment: @Somos How did you obtain, $a^2(q).a(q^5) = 1 + 12q + 36q^2 + 12q^3 + 84q^4 + 78q^5 + \cdots $

Comment: What is $a(q) $? It would be best to define it mathematically instead of saying that it is Borwein's theta function. Do you mean $a(q) =\sum_{m, n\in\mathbb {Z}} q^{m^2+mn+n^2}$?

Comment: @cabmetric Please consult [OEIS sequence A004016](https://oeis.org/A004016) with g.f. of $\,a(q)\,$  for more details. And yes, a(q) = sum_{m,n} q^(m^2+mn+n^2).

Comment: There is a Lambert series available for $a(q) $ obtained first by Ramanujan $$a(q) =1+6\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{q^{3n+1}}{1-q^{3n+1}}-\frac{q^{3n+2}}{1-q^{3n+2}}\right)$$ but I doubt if one can find some Lambert series for $a^2(q)a(q^5)$ easily. My guess is that it would involve a mixed modular equation of degrees $1,3,15$.

Comment: I hope the book by Cooper contains some elegant identity related to $a(q^2)a(q^5)$ which can help us here. Otherwise this is a very non-trivial task.